# Java - Implementing interface with Object argument

Tags: java, graph

I was implementing a Java Graph library (to learn ...). Accordingly, I wrote an interface

```
public interface DigraphInterface {
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public int size();
    public boolean isAdjacent(Object v, Object w);
    public void insertEdge(Object v, Object w);
    public void insertVertex(Object v);
    public void eraseEdge(Object o, Object w);
    public void eraseVertex(Object v);
    public void printDetails();
}
```

As the first step towards implementing, I am writing Digraph class that implements above interface. However, to keep things simple, I want the node identifiers as integers, so I defined functions as

```
    @Override
    public boolean isAdjacent(int v, int w) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return adjList[v].contains(w) || adjList[w].contains(v);
    }
```

But, I am getting error, that I need to override or implement method with supertype. Can someone explain me the underpinnings for this behavior. Also, if someone can explain, how do we design libraries that allow flexibility to add components of any type.

Comment: Apart from `int` not even being an `Object`, an implementation cannot give less promise than the interface. Your interface already promises to handle **any Object**.

Comment: So, How should I go about this ? I want that I need not change the interface, when I wish to implement another class that identifies nodes with strings or something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You interface says:

```
public boolean isAdjacent(Object v, Object w);
```

you implement:

```
public boolean isAdjacent(int v, int w)
```

for java this hasn't the same signature, therefore isn't the same method. What you could do is to use generics, it depends on what you need but, in this case you could do something like:

```
public interface DigraphInterface<T> {
    ...
    public boolean isAdjacent(T v, T w);
    ...
}
```

and your implementation could be:

```
public class DefaultDigraph<Integer> {
    ...
    public boolean isAdjacent(Integer v, Integer w) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

of course you need to take care, because `Integer` can be null, and `int` not. Therefore null checks over parameters would be a good idea, before its auto-unboxing.

Comment: I had the understanding that when we pass int to a method, Java automatically converts it into Object if required. If it does not find any method with int arguments, it must bind it to method with Object arguments. Thats what I thought.

Comment: yes, for invoking yes, when you invoke a method, the parameters are boxed into its WrapperClass, in this case `Integer`, but for method implementation the signature **MUST** be the same. And therefore this wouldn't work: `public boolean isAdjacent(int v, int w)`. Did you get it?

Comment: OK, Thanks Francisco for explaining me. I will use Generics to achieve this. My goal was to have one interface and several implementations that may identify nodes in different ways

Comment: You are welcome, but please, check for null values before unboxing, otherwise you will have other problems.